# Is a permission error causing this?

Tags: 12.04, permissions, vps

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 server with Digital Ocean and installed zPanel on it, now I'm trying to run [Pyd.io](http://Pyd.io) in zPanel's public_html and get the following error in the web browser-

```
realpath(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/glorbi_com:/var/zpanel/temp/)
```

Does anyone think this could be as a result of Ubuntu's permissions, or as a result of PHP messing up?

Cheers!

Karan

Comment: It is a php configuration problem of your open_basedir settings. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir You probably need to include /tmp as a valid directory since the valid directories seem to be `/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/glorbi_com` and `/var/zpanel/temp/` OR change the file that needs to be created from /tmp to `/var/zpanel/temp/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) manual:

> When a script tries to access the filesystem, for example using
>   include, or fopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the
>   file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to
>   access it.

It seems that your php `open_basedir` configuration allow these path:

```
  /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/glorbi_com:/var/zpanel/temp/
```

and `/tmp` is not in the list, this is why you got error.

Comment: Thank you! :-) I managed to change it by updating php.ini, httpd.vhost.conf to set the value to none and rebooting the machine.